# generic linked list pointer access

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, generic-list

I am writing a generic linked list in C++ using templates, and am experiencing Segmentation Faults when accessing Node values.

To make the test case simpler, I have implemented a fixed size, two node, linked list.

I have two questions:

1a) Why isn't aList.headNodePtr->prevNodePtr set to NULL?

1b) Why isn't aList.tailNodePtr->nextNodePtr set to NULL?

I set both of these values to NULL in the LinkedList constructor, but the output in main shows that:

```
head prevAddress: 0x89485ed18949ed31
tail nextAddress: 0x7fffe8849679
```

2) Why does the following line in main() cause a Seg Fault?

```
aList.headNodePtr->nodeValue = 1;
```

The full code is below:

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
    class Node {
    public:
    Node<T>* prevNodePtr;
    Node<T>* nextNodePtr;
    T nodeValue;
};

template <typename T>
    class LinkedList {
    public:
    Node<T>* headNodePtr;
    Node<T>* tailNodePtr;

    LinkedList() {
        Node<T>* headNodePtr = new Node<T>;
        Node<T>* tailNodePtr = new Node<T>;

        headNodePtr->prevNodePtr = NULL;
        headNodePtr->nextNodePtr = tailNodePtr;
        tailNodePtr->prevNodePtr = headNodePtr;
        tailNodePtr->nextNodePtr = NULL;
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        headNodePtr = NULL;
        tailNodePtr = NULL;
        delete headNodePtr;
        delete tailNodePtr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> aList;
    cout << "head Value: " << aList.headNodePtr->nodeValue << endl;
    cout << "head prevAddress: " << aList.headNodePtr->prevNodePtr << endl;
    cout << "head nextAddress: " << aList.headNodePtr->nextNodePtr << endl;
    cout << "tail Value: " << aList.tailNodePtr->nodeValue << endl;
    cout << "tail prevAddress: " << aList.tailNodePtr->prevNodePtr << endl;
    cout << "tail nextAddress: " << aList.tailNodePtr->nextNodePtr << endl;

    aList.headNodePtr->nodeValue = 1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you `delete`-ing `headNodePtr` and `tailNodePtr` **after** setting them to `NULL`? That's a memory leak right there. You need to `delete` them before setting to `NULL`. Also, I assume this is homework or something for your own independent study, as standard C++ already provides a `std::list` that is fully tested.

Comment: @in-silico thanks for explaining about delete. I was doing that because a previous bit of code was crashing from double-deletes, but obviously this "cure" is not the correct one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually setting the members, you're setting the locals you declared in the ctor:

```
Node<T>* headNodePtr;  // <-- MEMBERS
Node<T>* tailNodePtr;

LinkedList() {
    Node<T>* headNodePtr = new Node<T>;  // <-- LOCALS
    Node<T>* tailNodePtr = new Node<T>;
```

Try this instead:

```
Node<T>* headNodePtr;  // <-- MEMBERS
Node<T>* tailNodePtr;

LinkedList() {
    headNodePtr = new Node<T>;  // <-- MEMBER ACCESS
    tailNodePtr = new Node<T>;
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems obvious after you clued me in.

Comment: That's 90% of programming.  :)